# Why Azure function is not writing to Service Bus Topic

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

My function is like

```
    [FunctionName("MyFunctionName")]
    [return: ServiceBus("mytopic", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
    public static async Task<string> MyFunctionAsync([QueueTrigger("my-input-queue")] string msgIn, TraceWriter log)
    {
```

My **local.settings.json** has

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": "[my connection string]"
  }
}
```

where `[my connection string]` is copy-pasted from a **Primary Connecting String** under one of the **Shared access policies** with a **Send** claim.

This just silently fails: Messages get stuck in `my-input-queue` and no errors are written to log streaming. However I'm 100% sure the attribute is the issue because I've deployed 100 different combinations of this to try and make it work :).

Any ideas?

Comment: So, input messages are not processed and stay in your Storage Queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test，it should work with servicebus attribute. The following is my test code.

```
[return: ServiceBus("topicName",Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString", EntityType = EntityType.Topic)]
public static async Task<string>Run([QueueTrigger("queueName")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
   ...
   return myQueueItem; // write to the Topic.
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
 "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxxxxx",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "xxxxxxxx",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": "xxxxxx"
  }
}
```

You could get more information about Azure Service Bus output binding from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/service-bus#azure-service-bus-output-binding). You also could do that with follwoing way

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]
public static void Run([[QueueTrigger("queueName")]string myQueueItem,
                       TraceWriter log,
                       [ServiceBus("topicName",Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString", EntityType = EntityType.Topic)]out string queueMessage)
{
    log.Info("Azure Function Demo - Azure Service Bus Queue Topic");

    queueMessage = myQueueItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the required settings for your QueueTrigger, so your function isn't triggering on new items in the queue. You should have values for `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `AzureWebJobsDashboard`, and your QueueTrigger should have a value for the `Connection` field.

For more information about how to wire up QueueTriggers and test locally, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46795227/9035640).

Comment: No, that is not the problem. For example, if I change the return value to `Task` and get rid of the `[return: ..]` attribute, it picks up the messages in the queue.

Comment: So your function application is executing. Do you see logs about the function failing?