# How to convert Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity to Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableEntity

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I'm trying to migrate from classic Azure Table Storage to Cosmos DB with Azure Table API.  Starting on a particular data I want to start copying the current incoming Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity objects to Cosmos DB at the same time I write to the existing Azure Table Storage.

Is there a way to convert Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity to Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableEntity?

Comment: Please edit your question and include some code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot convert to microsoft.azure.cosmosDB.table.itableentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950037/cannot-convert-to-microsoft-azure-cosmosdb-table-itableentity). In all honesty even if you get rid of `WindowsAzure` and move to `CosmosDB`, the namespaces and methods are quite similar and shouldn't require too much changing.

Comment: Thanks - the problem I have is that I want to be able to push the same data to both storage types for a period of time.  Yes, just moving over completely is relatively trivial, but I'm not ready to do that yet.

Comment: In the end I just decided to serialize the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity objects and then deserialize them as Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableEntity.  A bit hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK I don't think you can do that so I would use an Automapper to transfer the data between the two model objects.

[Automapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/)